# is there possible to resolve this star pyramid

Tags: python

Today, i have trying to resolve a small star pyramid :

Input:

```
5 1
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
```

Code:

```
x = 1 
y = 0  
m, e = map(int, raw_input().split()) 
while x < m:
    print "\n" * y, "*" * e
    m -= 1 
    e += 1
```

I did that but there is a better solution?? Thanks =)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Comment: Couple things. y is always 0, so it never increases the number of newlines or actually prints a newline. If you always want it to start from one, then just take one input. Also consider using something like `for i in range(m)` instead of doing that weird while `x < m` where x is always going to be 1.

Comment: yes thank you I would do it next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be solved more easily:

```
stop, first = map(int, raw_input().split())
for i in range(stop - 1):
    print '*' * (i + first)
```

Comment: just `print '*' * i` as OP uses python 2.x

Comment: Thanks for your fast reponse ! :) But if i put as input 5 2 with your snippet, it does not add star :/

Comment: with your code, output is **
***
**** and me  **
 ***
 ****
 *****

Comment: sorry i have press enter i edit

Comment: The second parameter allows Defining the number of stars
in each lines

Comment: thanks you very much :) it is not possible to put it in one line ?

Comment: and just vote for my post because i would like vote for you post that very help me :) I have 14 < 15 lol

Comment: You could `print '\n'.join('*' * (first + i) for i in range(stop - 1))`

Comment: much nicer than mine :P

Comment: You are very strong. I will revise :D Thanks you for all.

Answer (score 1):

just for fun >:)

```
class c:
   def __init__(s,m,e):
      s.e , s.m = sorted([e, m])
      s.r = 42
   def __iter__(s):
      return s
   def next(s):
      if s.m < s.e:
         t = "".join(chr(s.r) for _ in range(s.m))
         s.m += 1
         return t
      else:
         raise StopIteration

print "\n".join(c(*map(int,raw_input().split())))
```

Comment: When you have an OOP hammer, everything looks like a class-based nail... Wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(raw_input())
for i in range(n): print "*"*i
```

This appears to do what your program intends to do, however I can't quite tell because of the issues I raised in my comment above.